# Adding duplicate object key with different value to another object in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Currently have this array data with objects

```
[
 {subjects: "Literature"},
 {subjects: "Science"},
 {ageLevels: "Preschool"}
]
```

My goal is to convert it to this data

```
[
 {subjects: "Literature", ageLevels: "Preschool"},
 {subjects: "Science"}
]
```

This is my current code, but it does not include the other subjects key. How do I include the other subjects and be in another object in 1 array?

```
let selectedFilters = [];
let selectedSubjects = ["Science", "Literature"];
let selectedAge = ["Preschool"];
let finalObj = {};

if (selectedSubjects.length > 0) {  
    selectedSubjects.forEach((element) => {
        let subj = {};
        subj.subjects = element;
        selectedFilters.push(subj);
    });
}

if (selectedAge.length > 0) {
    selectedAge.forEach((element) => {
        let age = {};
        age.ageLevels = element;
        selectedFilters.push(age);
    });
}
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFilters.length; i++) {
    Object.assign(finalObj, selectedFilters[i]);
}
```

Output of the finalObj:
{subjects: 'Literature', ageLevels: 'Preschool'}

Comment: How do you decide which subject(s) to apply age level(s) to? To me it sounds like you want something more like this: `{ subjects: ['Science', 'Literature'], ageLevels: 'Preschool' }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    subjects: "Literature"
  },
  {
    subjects: "Science"
  },
  {
    ageLevels: "Preschool"
  }
];

let selectedSubjects = ["Science", "Literature"];
let selectedAge = ["Preschool"];


let output = arr.map((e, i) => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('subjects')) {
    let condition = selectedAge[i];
    let obj = Object.assign(e, condition ? {
      "ageLevels": condition
    } : null);
    return obj
  }
}).filter(x => x !== undefined);

console.log(output);
```